# ¿Cómo activar mi alarma con una fecha?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una alarma que funciona de la siguiente manera, seleccionas una hora y minuto y todos los días a esa hora y minuto se envía una notificación, así lo hago y funciona correctamente:

```
public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    Log.i(TAG, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "9:30 (default)");

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

    // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
    // device is rebooted.
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context, String date, int idPersona) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + date);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);

        /** Obtiene datos para enviar en bundle **/
        intent.putExtra( "notification_id", idPersona);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        Persona persona = baseDatos.getPersona(idPersona);
        intent.putExtra("nombre", persona.getNombre());
        intent.putExtra("idPersona", persona.getId());
        intent.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());


        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idPersona, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

      String myDate[] = date.split(":");

    Log.i(TAG, "calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, " + myDate[0]);
    Log.i(TAG, "calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, " + myDate[1]);


         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(myDate[0]));
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(myDate[1]));

        //AlarmManager repeat every day
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "setAlarm() " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Pero ahora quiero que la notificación se envíe el día que yo quiera y no la hora, me explico.

Antes funcionaba así: 9:30 y todos los días a esa hora se envía la notificación.

Ahora lo que quiero hacer: 05/05 que sea mediante una FECHA y NO mediante la hora y que siempre que sea ese día se envíe la notificación, pero no funciona correctamente, se envía la notificación todos los días.

Así he intentado hacerlo:

```
public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);

    Log.i(TAG, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "05/05 (default)");

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

    // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
    // device is rebooted.
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context, String date, int idPersona) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + date);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);

        /** Obtiene datos para enviar en bundle **/
        intent.putExtra( "notification_id", idPersona);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        Persona persona = baseDatos.getPersona(idPersona);
        intent.putExtra("nombre", persona.getNombre());
        intent.putExtra("idPersona", persona.getId());
        intent.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());


        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idPersona, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

      String myDate[] = date.split("/");

        Log.i(TAG, "calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, " + myDate[0]);
        Log.i(TAG, "calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, " + myDate[1]);

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(myDate[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(myDate[1]));

        //AlarmManager repeat every day
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "setAlarm() " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué se envía la notificación todos los días y no el que selecciono?

Gracias :)

Comment: Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

porque le pusiste setRepeating. El código correcto sería así:
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @armen ! ahora si funciona por dia/mes pero, no se vuelve a reactivar la alarma, por ejemplo: configuro una alarma, 10/5 cuando esa alarma mande la notificación que se reactive automáticamente para el próximo 10/5, me comprendes? Es para una aplicación de Cumpleaños, por lo tanto se debería reactivar la alarma cada vez que mande la notificación, para que así todos los años este activada. Me he explicado bien? Gracias !

Comment: no creo que se pueda por año, pues no existe el INTERVAL_YEAR. Lo que podrías hacer es almacenar
las fechas utilizando un for loop de aquí a (50 años te parece?), mas no se si todavía se usarán los
telefonos inteligentes para entonces. Ejemplo de un for loop para agregar año tras año :
for(int i=1; i<50; i++) {
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,1);
}